# Any Language to interop with C++?

Tags: c++, interop

Are there any modern languages that can directly interop with C/C++? I mean directly like Java does with Kotlin. A language that can take advantage of the C/C++ ecosystem without major performance compromises.

I like C/C++ areas of interest but not the language.

Comment: C++11 let alone C++17 is not old. And only folk from the future can claim that C++20 is old. Yes, the Java guys did a really good job with the JNI for interop with C and C++.

Comment: C yes, C++, not so much

Comment: C interops just fine with C++. As does Lua.

Comment: What does the *age* of a language have to do with *anything*? Either a language is fit for purpose or it is not, how many years it has existed should be (*is*) irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists an intersection of C and C++ that is a subset of both languages. Function declarations written in this subset can be called from either language.

C is the de facto interoperability language, and in addition to C++, most other high level languages that support language interoperability at all support C in particular. And inter operation of languages other than C, with languages other than C, often goes through this C interface of both languages.

Due to the high degree of support for C interfaces in C++, this interoperability can usually be taken advantage of in C++ as well, but the interface is limited to the features in the common subset.

You mention Java specifically. It is an example of a language that has an interoperability layer with C.

---

All languages that support general inter-process communication (such as sockets), are generally interoperable through that communication with other processes written in any language.

---

> Can I use C++ library from Java ...

If the library has an interface written in the interoperable subset of C, then yes. A wrapper interface can be written if it doesn't exist yet.

> ... and expect to have the same performance as with C/C++?

The foreign language interface may have some overhead, and the Java side itself may involve overhead that is not present when using the library natively. Whether this overhead is significant, you can find out by measuring. I would expect it to be less than overhead of socket communication for example.

Furthermore, inter-procedural optimisation probably won't be possible. It is similar in this regard to using a shared library in the native C or C++.

Comment: "There exists an intersection of C and C++ that is a subset of both languages" - Awesome tautology. That in itself is worth an upvote.

Comment: @Bathsheba The "tautology" is there to make it extra clear that C itself is not that subset. I'd say it is redundancy rather than tautology though.

Comment: Can I use C++ library from Java and expect to have the same performance as with C/C++?

Comment: @Antony C++ doesn't have a standardized ABI so directly interfacing with a C++ library is very difficult.  C does, so it is quite easy.

Comment: @eeronika So I guess we're stuck with C++ for many years to come whether we like it or not

Comment: @Antony If you write your libraries in Java, then you don't need to use C++.